# Getting GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'chand' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.vproc.member.MyUserDetails' in grails app

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I am working on grails app where as admin, I can add subscribers to my application.When I try to add new subscriber via subscriber/create, a mail will go to provided email id and then subscriber has to click on link provided in email. But When subscriber fills all information,and click, I am getting following error.

```
Cannot cast object 'chand' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.vproc.member.MyUserDetails'. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'chand' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.vproc.member.MyUserDetails'
```

Getting error in following method from **SubscriberService.groovy**

```
def Subscriber getLoggedinSubscriber(){

        if (springSecurityService.principal != null ){
    //Getting error in below line.  
 MyUserDetails userDetails = (MyUserDetails)springSecurityService.principal
            Subscriber subscriber =  userDetails.currentSubscriber ;
            //subscriber.customer.party
            return subscriber

        }else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

MyUserDetailsService.groovy

```
package com.vrpoc.service.member

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.vproc.member.Customer;
import com.vproc.member.MyUserDetails;
import com.vproc.member.Organization;
import com.vproc.member.Person;
import com.vproc.member.Subscriber;
import com.vproc.member.SubscriberRole;

@Transactional
class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    def springSecurityServivce

    static final List NO_ROLES = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }


    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Subscriber.withTransaction {
            status ->

            Person user = Person.findByUsername(username)
            if (!user)
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException( 'User not found', username)

            def session = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session
            def params = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().params
            def newOrgId = params["orgId"]

            List<Subscriber> subscribers = []
            List<Organization> orgs = []
            def currentSubscriber = null
            if ( session["orgs"] == null && newOrgId == null){
                subscribers = Subscriber.findAllByParty( user) // get all subscribers for this person

                subscribers.each {  orgs.add(it.customer.party ) }  // get all customer and then orgs for subscribers
                session["orgs"] = orgs   // add orgs to session
                session["currentOrg"] = orgs.get(0);

                currentSubscriber = subscribers.get(0)
                currentSubscriber.contacts.size()

            }else if ( newOrgId){

                def currentOrgId = newOrgId
                Organization organization = Organization.get(currentOrgId)
                session["currentOrg"] = organization;
                Customer customer = Customer.findByParty( organization)
                currentSubscriber = Subscriber.findByCustomerAndParty( customer, user)
            }

        println  currentSubscriber.customer.party.orgName

            /*
            def newContextOrgId = session["currentOrgId"]
            def currentSubscriber = session["currentSubscriber"]
            if ( newContextOrgId == null ){
                def customer = Customer.findByParty( Organization.get(newContextOrgId))
                def person  = Person.get(springSecurityServivce.principal.id );
                subscriber = Subscriber.findByPartyAndCustomer( person, customer)
                session["currentSubscriber"] = subscriber
            } */


            def authorities = SubscriberRole.findAllBySubscriber(currentSubscriber).collect  {
                new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.role.authority)
            } as Set

            return new MyUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled, !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired, !user.accountLocked,
                                        authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id, user.firstName , user.lastName,  currentSubscriber )
        }
    }

}
```

Not: Any idea why this is happening. Let me know you need more code to be displayed here.

Comment: Try `springSecurityService.currentUser` in place of `springSecurityService.principal`

Comment: hi @tim_yates , though new subscriber successfully added to system. But first I have to log out from app, then I can log in with new subscrber(on local host).

Comment: hi, @tim_yates with your suggestion, I can not even log in to my application. Any other suggestion to get it done? –

Comment: Can you add `MyUserDetails` as well?

Comment: hi @dmahapatro , I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: hi @drorb, any idea why error is occurring?

Comment: @Vieenay sorry, no idea. My best advice would be debugging the spring security plugin code starting at SpringSecurityService.getPrincipal()

Answer (score 0):

Normally when this happens, you need to change the parametre name, for example,

```
def some_name(String some_name)
{ 
   Some operation here
}
```

Change the name some_name to let say `'p'`, just `(p)`

So that your method changes to

```
def some_name(String p)
{ 
   Some operation here
}
```

This will confuse the controller as to the same name being used, thus the same method name and parametre name. It will be lost trying to find out what exactly you trying to do